# elasticsearch match query returns empty results for nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am following this [link](https://project-a.github.io/on-site-search-design-patterns-for-e-commerce/#full-text-search)
I have an index `test_products` with following `mapping`:

```
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
},
"mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "search_result_data": {
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "path_match": "search_result_data.*"
            }
        }
        ],
    "properties": {
        "search_data": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "full_text": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "string_facet": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "facet-name": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "facet-value": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And a document inserted with following format:

```
    {
  "search_result_data": {
    "sku": "wheel-6075-90092",
    "gtin": null,
    "name": "Matte Black Wheel Fuel Ripper",
    "preview_image": "abc.jg",    
    "url": "9836817354546538796",
    "brand": "Fuel Off-Road"
  },
  "search_data": 
    {
      "full_text": "Matte Black Wheel Fuel Ripper",
      "string_facet": [
        {
          "facet-name": "category",
          "facet-value": "Motor Vehicle Rims & Wheels"
        },
        {
          "facet-name": "brand",
          "facet-value": "Fuel Off-Road"
        }
      ]
    }    
}
```

and few other documents..

I am trying to full-text search the index with following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "search_data.full_text": "Black"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting empty results for this query although the field contains term `Black`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `search_data` field is `nested` you need to use [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) as well:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "search_data",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "search_data.full_text": "Black"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```